# Multiple Modal Pop-ups to show different Images

Tags: javascript, modalpopup

I'm a noob at coding but I am trying to make a team members' page where their image is clicked on and then another image pops up showing their description etc. I have copied a code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp and then found a suggestion on StackOverflow in which I implemented their code onto mine. The only problem is I cannot get the other image to be clicked on and show a different image.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/dm1010101/pen/wvmQPej
Here is the JS code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 span.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id on both images.

I used custom function `img_click` and passed the clicked element with it like this `onClick="img_click(this)"` and now your both images clicks are working fine and showing alts saved on those images. And ofcourse Id's are not needed as you are passing `this` with your function calling.

This this snippet.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
function img_click(img){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
}


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* CSS for the team page*/
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
/*end of css for team members*/
```

```html
<img onClick="img_click(this)" src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/4388/wiki/tester-image.png" alt="pug" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/4388/wiki/tester2.png">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <img onClick="img_click(this)" src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/4388/wiki/tester-image.png" alt="pugq" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
</div>
```